# imacros solve solvemedia captcha

Tags: javascript, captcha, imacros

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
FILEDELETE NAME=c:\temp\captcha.jpg
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=c:\temp\ FILE=captcha.jpg
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:adcopy-puzzle-image-image CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=http://www.9kw.eu/grafik/form.html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:apikey CONTENT=--API KEY HERE--
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:prio CONTENT=0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:source CONTENT=imacros
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:file-upload-01 CONTENT=C:\temp\captcha.jpg
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=TYPE:submit
WAIT SECONDS=35
TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=NAME:result EXTRACT=TXT
TAB CLOSE
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=ID:adcopy_response CONTENT={{!EXTRACT}}
WAIT SECONDS=5
```

This is the imacros code I got for solving solvemedia captchas. The problem when I run it is that it doesn't find the tag on line 5. How should I change it to copy the solvemedia image?

Another error is when I try to convert and run it as javascript, It just fails from the first command

```
FILEDELETE NAME=c:\temp\captcha.jpg
```

giving me error "wrong format of FILEDELETE command, line 1 (Error code: 910)"

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Here is how to delete your file with the help of js-script: `iimPlayCode("FILEDELETE NAME=C:\\Temp\\ captcha.jpg");` If you want to copy the solvemedia image like [this](http://screencast.com/t/SCjn4NCDcR) after clicking the 'Play' button, contact me via e-mail ( shugarjs@gmail.com ) and I’ll give you a js-script to try.

Answer (score 1):

I think you use iMacros with Chrome but then it's impossible with FILEDELETE. See http://wiki.imacros.net/FILEDELETE

You can use iMacros for Firefox with your example or try my full example with your solvemedia captcha and 9kw:

1. media.iim

   ```html
   SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
   SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
   SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 999
   SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 999
   TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
   '
   ' Note for users with firefox with the message "Firefox prevented this page from automatically reloading.":
   ' UNCHECK the option "warn me when pages try to redirect" in your browser
   ' You find the checkbox under Options > Advanced > General > Accessibility

   ' Path to the captcha image with timestamp
   ' Tempfolder like C:\ or C:\TEMP under windows or like /tmp under linux
   SET !VAR0 C:\
   ' Tempfile
   SET !VAR1 captcha_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}}.jpg

   ' Step 1: Config for 9kw.eu for your apikey
   SET !VAR2 your_api_key
   'And priority (prio 1-20)
   SET !VAR3 0

   ' Step 2: Save the captcha picture to local disk
   TAB T=1
   URL GOTO=http://www.solvemedia.com/publishers/captcha-type-in
   WAIT SECONDS=3
   ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER={{!VAR0}} FILE={{!VAR1}} WAIT=YES
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:adcopy-puzzle-image-image-profit CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT

   'Wait a random number (1 to 5) of seconds
   SET !VAR9 EVAL("Math.floor(Math.random()*5 + 1);")
   WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR9}}

   'Syntaxcheck: API Key, prio
   SET !VAR2 EVAL("var s=\"{{!VAR2}}\"; if(s.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/) && s.length <= 50 && s.length >= 5) s; else MacroError(\"API Key is wrong.\")")
   SET !VAR3 EVAL("var s=\"{{!VAR3}}\", d = parseFloat(s); if(d >= 0 && d <= 20) d; else MacroError(\"Value(Prio) is not in the set range.\")")

   'Step 3: Open the a new tab, and go to 9kw.eu, and submit the captcha picture
   TAB OPEN
   TAB T=2
   URL GOTO=http://www.9kw.eu/grafik/form.html
   'The apikey is used to identify each of our customers, which you can get from the our page. It is assigned to the CONTENT.
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:apikey CONTENT={{!VAR2}}
   'Priority in our system like min. 0 to max. 20 (cost +0-20)
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:prio CONTENT={{!VAR3}}
   'Options for the form. See more under http://www.9kw.eu/grafik/form.html and http://www.9kw.eu/api.html
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/index.cgi ATTR=NAME:selfsolve CONTENT=NO
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/index.cgi ATTR=NAME:confirm CONTENT=NO
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/index.cgi ATTR=NAME:case-sensitive CONTENT=NO
   'TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ACTION:/index.cgi ATTR=NAME:nomd5 CONTENT=YES
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:source CONTENT=imacros
   'The path of the captcha picture saved is assigned to the CONTENT
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:file-upload-01 CONTENT={{!VAR0}}{{!VAR1}}
   'Submit the formdata to 9kw.eu
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=TYPE:submit
   'Extract the captchaid from your captcha submit
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:captchaid EXTRACT=TXT
   SET !VAR5 {{!EXTRACT}}
   'Clean the !EXTRACT variable for the next task
   SET !EXTRACT NULL
   'Extract the characters that are recoginzed from the picture of captcha.
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:result EXTRACT=TXT
   TAB CLOSE
   TAB T=1

   'Display extracted data (only for debug)
   'PROMPT {{!VAR5}}

   'Step 4: Check the captcha answer (text or nothing like #EANF# = Extraction Anchor Not Found)
   SET !VAR6 EVAL("if (\"{{!EXTRACT}}\" == \"#EANF#\") {var x = \"\";} else {var x = \"{{!EXTRACT}}\";} x;")
   'Clean the !EXTRACT variable for the next task
   SET !EXTRACT NULL

   'Step 5: Fill the recognized characters to the verification box
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:demo_form ATTR=ID:adcopy_response-profit CONTENT={{!VAR6}}
   WAIT SECONDS=5
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:verify_profit
   WAIT SECONDS=4

   'Step 6: Check and send the captcha feedback back to the captcha service (OK:1, NotOK:2, EN: Right/False, DE: Richtig/Falsch)
   'SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"greencheck.png\" style=\"display: ([^;]+);" IGNORE_CASE=YES EXTRACT="$1"
   TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:profit-correct EXTRACT=HTM
   SET !VAR7 {{!EXTRACT}}
   SET !EXTRACT NULL
   SET !VAR8 EVAL("if ('{{!VAR7}}'.match(/style=\"display: block/)) {var x = \"1\";} else {var x = \"2\";} x;")
   TAB OPEN
   TAB T=2
   URL GOTO=http://www.9kw.eu/index.cgi?source=imacros&action=usercaptchacorrectback&apikey={{!VAR2}}&correct={{!VAR8}}&id={{!VAR5}}
   WAIT SECONDS=2
   TAB CLOSE
   TAB T=1

   'Cleanup: Delete the old captcha picture
   FILEDELETE NAME={{!VAR0}}{{!VAR1}}
   ```